# Collision Detection without Coordinates in Tilemaps in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, coordinates, collision-detection

I am programming a Bomberman game, right now I don't have any sprites but I use rectangles for it.
This is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WinWidth = 800
WinHeight = 608
p1x = 32
p1y = 32
vel = 1
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WinWidth, WinHeight))

def player():
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 200, 200), (p1x, p1y, 32, 32))


player_rect = pygame.Rect(p1x, p1y, tlw, tlh)


class Wall:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (50, 50, 50), (x, y, 32, 32))


class Breakable:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 150, 100), (x, y, 32, 32))


game_map1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 0],
             [0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 10, 10, 10, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 10, 10, 10, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0],
             [0, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

run = True
while run:

    pygame.init()

    clock.tick(100)
    win.fill((0, 255, 200))
    y = 0
    for layer in game_map1:
        x = 0
        for tile in layer:
            if tile == 0:
                Wall(x * 32, y * 32)
                wall_rect = pygame.Rect(x * 32, y * 32, tlw, tlh)
            if tile == 10:
                pygame.Rect(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32)
            if tile == 2:
                Breakable(x * 32, y * 32)
            x += 1
        y += 1

    player()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_d:
        if player_rect.colliderect(wall_rect):
            p1x *= -1
            p1y *= -1
        else:
            p1x += vel
    elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
        if player_rect.colliderect(wall_rect):
            p1x *= -1
            p1y *= -1
        else:
            p1x -= vel
    if event.key == pygame.K_s:
        if player_rect.colliderect(wall_rect):
            p1x *= -1
            p1y *= -1
        else:
            p1y += vel
    elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
        if player_rect.colliderect(wall_rect):
            p1x *= -1
            p1y *= -1
        else:
            p1y -= vel
        

    pygame.display.update()
```

The `x` and `y` are at the top-left of the player rectangle - They are `p1x` and `p1y`.

Width and Height are `tlw` and `tlh`.

The Wall and Breakable are using `tlw` and `tlh`, too and they do not have their specific coordinates like the player has.

sooo... I watched a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCWI2f7tQnY&t=2s) and even tried to make a collision detection on my own. But I just can't do it. I don't have coordinates for the rectangles in the tilemap and there are very much rectangles in the tilemap, too. How could you make a collision detection with a tilemap with no coordinates and many rectangles? And yeah, the game doesn't have much stuff going on for now... I tried it with the pygame.Rect's `player_rect` and `wall_rect` and then using `(colliderect)` but it didn't work and how can you make it the player_rect collides with ALL wall_rect's and not only with one.

My question is: ***How do I make a collision detection with the tilemaps with colliderect?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have refactored the entire code because the code you posted throws an error and i couldn't test my code. The way we have implemented collision detection here works but is not really effective. If you want to know which side is colliding so you can implement the game logic, then `colliderect` is quite pointless. I suggest you ask a new question on how to build custom collision detection, since it's an entirely new topic but the following code solves the original question of how to implement collision detection using colliderect. The following example also shows how draw functions should be a separate method, which is the better way to do it. Btw, if `tile == 10` you had put `pygame.Rect(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32)` in your question which basically does nothing, so i put `pass`. If  you want it to be a new type of wall, you can make a new class similar to `Breakable` and `Wall`. Final answer, hope it helped :).

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WinWidth = 800
WinHeight = 608
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((WinWidth, WinHeight))

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 32
        self.y = 32
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.vel = 0.1

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 200, 200), (self.x, self.y, 32, 32))

    def getRect(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


class Wall:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect =  rect
        self.x = rect.x
        self.y = rect.y
   
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (50, 50, 50), self.rect)

    def getRect(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)


class Breakable:
    def __init__(self, rect):
        self.rect = rect
        self.x = rect.x
        self.y = rect.y

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 150, 100), self.rect)

    def getRect(self):
        return pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32)


game_map1 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 0],
             [0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 10, 10, 10, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 10, 10, 10, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 10, 2, 2, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
             [0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 10, 0],
             [0, 10, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 10, 10, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


walls = []
y = 0
for layer in game_map1:
    x = 0
    for tile in layer:
        if tile == 0:
            walls.append(Wall(pygame.Rect([x*32, y*32, 32, 32])))
        if tile == 10:
            pass
        if tile == 2:
            walls.append(Breakable(pygame.Rect([x*32, y*32, 32, 32])))
        x += 1
    y += 1


player = Player()
pygame.init()
run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(100)
    win.fill((0, 255, 200))

    for i in range(len(walls)):
        walls[i].draw()

    player.draw()
        
    for wall in walls:
        if player.getRect().colliderect(wall.getRect()): #getRect is the method we added to wall class earlier
             print("they are colliding")    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            for wall in walls:
                wall_rect = wall.getRect()
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    if player.getRect().colliderect(wall_rect):
                        player.x *= -1
                        player.y *= -1
                    else:
                        player.x += player.vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if player.getRect().colliderect(wall_rect):
                        player.x *= -1
                        player.y *= -1
                    else:
                        player.x -= player.vel
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    if player.getRect().colliderect(wall_rect):
                        player.x *= -1
                        player.y *= -1
                    else:
                        player.y += player.vel
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    if player.getRect().colliderect(wall_rect):
                        player.x *= -1
                        player.y *= -1
                    else:
                        player.y -= player.vel
                    

    pygame.display.update()
```

Regarding your last question:

```
#Checks if right side of rect1 is colliding with left side of rect2
def rightCheck(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x:
        if (rect1.y > rect2.y and rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height) or (rect1.y + rect1.height < rect2.y + rect2.height and rect1.y + rect1.height> rect2.y):
            if rect1.x < rect2.x:
                return True
    return False

#Checks if top side of rect1 is colliding with bottom side of rect2
def topCheck(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height:
        if (rect1.x > rect2.x and rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width) or (rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x and rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x + rect2.width):
            if rect1.y > rect2.y:
                return True
    return False
 
#Checks if bottom side of rect1 is colliding with top side of rect2
def botCheck(rect1, rect2):
    if rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y:
        if (rect1.x > rect2.x and rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width) or (rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x and rect1.x + rect1.width < rect2.x + rect2.width):
            if rect1.y < rect2.y:
                return True
    return False
```

These are custom collision detection functions you can use. I haven't got the one for left side of the player (rect1) but i will try to make it later or you can try and make one as well. You can try to improve the ones i have provided to fit your game as well. Using these you can figure out exactly which side is colliding, and add useful logic. Example:

```
#have different velocities for every side
player_right_speed = 2
player_left_speed = 2

# Say that your player moves according to the following key presses
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
   playerx += player_right_speed
if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
   playerx -= player_left_speed

#you can call the collision detection functions to check if they are colliding and if they are set the speed in that direction to 0
#notice these functions take pygame.Rect as an argument
right_colliding = rightCheck(playerRect, tileRect)
if right_colliding:
   player_right_speed = 0
left_colliding = leftCheck(playerRect, tileRect)
if left_colliding:
   player_left_speed = 0
```

Comment: ok... can you make it a bit clearer for ME? I am not saying it is very unclear but I am new to pygame and I do not know much and if you look I already have wall_rect and player_rect

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the actual question I had. How you see I have colliderect. I will update the questoin. Sorry for your waste of time. It was my fault

Comment: So the collision is working, YAAAY! But umm the tilemap isn't working anymore... Is there anyway for us to talk privately so I can show you my current code? And did you try your answer for yourself before telling it me?

Comment: You can ask another question with your new problem

Comment: I can't. I am post-banned. And the new problem happened because I did what you told me to do. The walls = [] and walls.append() part

Comment: There are no problems anymore. The code i  have provided above draws blocks and checks for collision using `colliderect` which was your question

Comment: Sry, ummm forget the last comment. I didn't test it. I do not know why I commented that if I didn't test it. I think it was because I didn't saw you edited it again... sry

Comment: THANK YOU IT IS WORKING!!! But can I ask you one more question to this one? If there is a collision you can see that the `player.x` and `player.y` are ` *= -1`. Can you tell me another solution how I can make the player stand at the place? Not freeze or something like that?

Comment: I have extended the answer.